# ‘TopicQuery’ is not a member of ‘rosbag’

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

When I try to build my package via rosmake I get an error

```
error: ‘TopicQuery’ is not a member of ‘rosbag’
```

The line that generates an error:

```
rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery(topics));
```

The bag file and topics are initialized as follows:

```
rosbag::Bag bag;
bag.open("test.bag", rosbag::bagmode::Read);
std::vector<std::string> topics;
topics.push_back(std::string("chatter"));
topics.push_back(std::string("numbers"));
```

I am new to ROS, so maybe someone could suggest what seems to be the problem?
P.S. I followed [this](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosbag/html/c++/) tutorial

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32472/%E2%80%98topicquery%E2%80%99-is-not-a-member-of-%E2%80%98rosbag%E2%80%99/) by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-04-24**:
Please paste your entire program (or the smallest snippet that reproduces the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I realized that I just forgot the

```
#include "rosbag/view.h"
```

So now it works, sorry for inconvenience.

I don't have enough karma to close my own question, so please feel free to do it.

---

Originally posted by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) with karma: 386 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-04-25**:
I'll vote you up instead; after all, this is the right answer (no matter who found it).